# SwiftUI refresh list while maintaining current scroll position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a `List` in SwiftUI that I need to refresh but maintain current scroll position after refresh. I could do this in `UITableView` in UIKit but it seems impossible in SwiftUI. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you have **iOS 17** otherwise you should use `ScrollView`.

Comment: How does it work on iOS 17? I know about `ScrollView` but not for `List`.

Comment: I don't know but it just works if the iPhone or simulator works on iOS 17. Maybe Apple fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't added code here, Please make sure you are following this thing in your code:

1. do not create IDs on UI. Provide an Identifiable array using ViewModel.
2. refresh array data on ViewModel.

List will be refreshed once you refresh data. That is a main feature of SwiftUI. You don't need to refresh like UITableView in UIKit. I suggest you to study more about SwiftUI.